# Prevent accidental moving mails Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, plugins, undo

**Thunderbird moves mails and mail folders without request by drag and drop.**

This can happen by accident, if a user clicks on a mail folder and moves the mouse a little (using a bad mouse, or reading mails on a train...).

Once Thunderbird started to move a folder with a few thousand mails it can not be stopped.

**What can the user do to prevent this?** Is there a plugin that raises a last warning before moving? Is there any way to monitor and undo the movements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this [Disable DragAndDrop (Thunderbird)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/disable-draganddrop-thunderbir/) extension that will prevent drag-and-drop behavior

[image: disable drag and drop picture]